# Saving a reference to the path of the configuration file

Tags: configuration, config, configuration-files

How do I preserve the custom file path (chosen by the user) to a program's configuration file between runs of the program?

For example:

```
First time running program:

  User:     *opens program for first time*
  Program:  "What is the path to the configuration file for me?"
  User:     *choses path* "Right *here*."
  Program:  "OK, loading configuration file..."
  User:     *closes program*


Running the program a second time:

  User:     *opens program*
  Program:  "What is the path to the configuration file for me?"
  User:     "Why don't you remember?"
```

How do I fix this issue?

Obviously I can't store the path to the configuration file *in* the configuration file, that makes no sense. So the question stands: where can I store the path that the user chose to the configuration file?